# How to use multiple segments with and condition in it for Google Analytics API while using in Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-analytics

While code in python3 for Google Analytics API I am stuck at a point where I have to use Multiple Segment in the condition. But as per the GA's API Doc the way I use the code will only return me the data in the "**OR**" condition but I want the result to be in "**AND**" condition.

Result I want:

> sessions::condition::ga:pagePath=@/xxxxx;ga:eventAction==xxxxx

but the current result:

> sessions::condition::ga:pagePath=@/xxxxx,ga:eventAction==xxxxx

The code for the segment will be something like as below which is giving me the result in "**OR**" condition is

```
"segments":[{"dynamicSegment":{"name":"Page","sessionSegment":{"segmentFilters":[{"simpleSegment":{"orFiltersForSegment":[{"segmentFilterClauses":[{"dimensionFilter":{"dimensionName":"ga:pagePath","expressions":["/xxxxx"],"operator":"PARTIAL"}}]}]}}]}}}, {"dynamicSegment":{"name":"UpGrade","sessionSegment":{"segmentFilters":[{"simpleSegment":{"orFiltersForSegment":[{"segmentFilterClauses":[{"dimensionFilter":{"dimensionName":"ga:eventAction","expressions":["xxxxx"],"operator":"EXACT"}}]}]}}]}}}]
```

Can any  one help in the above code so I can have the output in "**AND**" condition.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the segment in the Google Analytics Interface (with the rules you prefer), so you can use in the API the ID of that segment instead of creating it at runtime in your code.

### How to do it:

Create the segment in Google Analytics, apply it and see the URL.

Example:

```
https://www.google.com/analytics/web/#report/visitors-overview/a11111111w22222222p33333333/%3F_.advseg%3Duser1234567890/
```

You are looking for `_.advseg` or `_.useg` parameter. In this case the segment ID is *user1234567890* (characters %3D mean encoded equal sign "=").

So, in API you can use directly:

```
segment=gaid::user1234567890
```

In this way you define the **AND** and the **OR** in the interface and you can see immediately if that segment is what you need to use it in the API.

Comment: Michele :-> My kind regards and thanks for the suggestion but I am well aware about the segment use with GID code but I want to create a Dynamic segment in which I have to modify some specific  values in real time so I am looking a way to use the "**AND**" condition in the python code.

Comment: Hi, I tried to simulate your segments once using the ";" and once there "," and I get two different results, so I'd say the different symbols work as you put them. Have you checked the result you get in the interface?

Comment: Brother, I am trying to fetch the data using the GA's API call and in that case ";" doesn't work and gives error while running the code.

Comment: Try it before with query explorer: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/